# Testing (RSpec) with Devise's confirmable module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

It's my understanding that Rails' testing environment is torn down and rebuilt before each test...so how do I test a controller that requires that a user be logged in and that user can't be created without Device's confirmable module getting in the way?

Devise's [recommended method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Rails-3-and-RSpec) (below) creates a new user which is then sent an email by Devise's `confirmable` module. How do I get around this so I'm not 'creating' a user each time...or if I am I can get an object to test w/out "simulating" a new email for each spec?

```
 before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something painfully obvious as this must be a very common spec for anyone using Devise with confirmable...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your test environment `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` should be set to `:test`, which means that these emails will not be sent out. If this setting is set to something else such as `smtp` by way of a configuration in say `config/environments.rb`, then emails *will* be sent out.

If that setting's already there, then to use the `User` object (as in, to be actually able to log in) you'll need to call `confirm!` on it:

```
user = User.first
user.confirm!
```

Comment: you could also move the creation of the user to a `before(:all)` block, to speed it up...

Comment: I did have to add `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` to get tests to run...otherwise `test.rb` is boilerplate, to my knowledge. Only mail related configs in `test.rb` or `environment.rb` is: `  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`.

Comment: so is `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` different in some way to the auto-generated `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`??

Comment: ok. backing up. the emails weren't sent out to begin with because of the test.rb setting. The problem was that the user record wasn't active (or whatever term Devise uses) so they couldn't log in... Every time the user is created before these tests it sits in a limbo state waiting to be "confirmed" while the tests fail...

Comment: @Meltemi: Right, which is why you should be calling `@user.confirm!` on the record before trying to do anything to it. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: OK, getting closer. `@user.confirm!` is helpful and a step in right direction! but, it's still not working as I've got a new cryptic error: `undefined method 'env' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: this may need to be updated, on devise-4.7.1 it seems `@user.confirm` works but `@user.confirm!` is not defined `NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm!' for #<User:0x0000562eca83c2b0>
Did you mean?  confirm`

Answer (score 19):

for latest FactoryGirl version:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :confirmed_user, :parent => :user do
    after(:create) { |user| user.confirm }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using factory_girl to generate your models, you can use `after_create` to confirm each new user.

```
Factory.define :confirmed_user, :parent => :user do |f|
  f.after_create { |user| user.confirm! }
end
```

Comment: I believe that you will get the same effect by adding `confirmed_at Time.now` as a factory attribute.

Answer (score 10):

For Devise 4.2 it's now `confirm` (not `confirm!`).

[Source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#420---2016-07-01)

> 4.2.0 - 2016-07-01
>
> Remove the Devise::Models::Confirmable#confirm! method, use confirm instead.

Code below also prevents mailers from being generated thanks to `after(:build)` vs `after(:create)` for setting `confirmed_at`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    after(:build)   { |u| u.skip_confirmation_notification! }
    after(:create)  { |u| u.confirm }
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Today it is just put:

confirmed_at 7.days.ago

on your fabrication

Answer (score 2):

Try stubbing `active?`

```
@user = Factory.create(:user)
@user.stub(:active?).and_return(true)
sign_in @user
```

You might also need to stub `confirmed?`, I'm not too familiar with Devise.

Answer (score 2):

This thread hasn't seen much traffic in a while, but for people who have this question now, all you need to do is create a trait called `:confirmed` that sets the required attributes, and when you use it to create a user, you will be able to log in with it without requiring multiple saves of the user db records.

```rb
  # Use faker library (installed separately) to set realistic seed data
  require 'faker'

  # Factory definition
  factory :user, do
    email { Faker::Internet.unique.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(min_length: 12, max_length: 128) }

    trait :confirmed do
      confirmed_at { Time.zone.now }
      confirmation_sent_at { Time.zone.now }
      confirmation_token { '12345' }
    end
  end

  # Example of using it
  user = create(:user, :confirmed)
```

Answer (score 1):

For fabrication gem it is

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  after_build { |user| user.confirm! }
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it require `after_create`, not `after_build`?