# Where do I confirm user created with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, devise-confirmable

Using rails, devise, rspec & factorygirl:

Trying to create some tests for my site. I'm using the confirmable model for devise so when I create a user using FactoryGirl, the user isn't confirmed.

This is my factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    full_name             "Aren Admin"
    email                 "aren@example.com"
    password              "arenaren"
    password_confirmation "arenaren"
    role_id               ADMIN
  end
end
```

And this is my rspec test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Admin pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "home page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit admin_home_path }

    it { should have_content("#{ROLE_TYPES[user.role_id]}") }
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error because the user is not confirmed. By searching around I'm pretty sure I need to use the method 'confirm!' and that it belongs in the factories.rb file, but I'm not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `user.confirm!` in your `before` block

found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Comment: Your link is outdated. And which "before" block is it? Could you please give us an example?

Answer (score 35):

You could also set the confirmed_at attribute as follows. Works for me:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    full_name             "Aren Admin"
    email                 "aren@example.com"
    password              "arenaren"
    password_confirmation "arenaren"
    role_id               ADMIN
    confirmed_at          Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: I have been preferring this method over `confirm!` because it is one less operation.

Comment: replaced two lines with one...and a little more intuitive, imo. Thanks!

Comment: This is the cleanest way to do it. Thanks :+1:

Comment: Note that `Time.now` would be executed when the factory is defined, not when the user object is created. It's recommended to pass a block like `confirmed_at { Time.now }` to set `confirmed_at` when it's created.

Answer (score 24):

Better yet, do the following (then you don't need to create a before filter for every test suite)

```
Factory.define :confirmed_user, :parent => :user do |f|
  f.after_create { |user| user.confirm! }
end
```

found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770075/1153149

**Edit to add non-deprecated syntax**

```
FactoryGirl.define do |f|
  #Other factory definitions

  factory :confirmed_user, :parent => :user do
    after_create { |user| user.confirm! }
  end
end
```

**Edit 01/27 To Update Syntax Again**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  #Other factory definitions

  factory :confirmed_user, :parent => :user do
    after(:create) { |user| user.confirm! }
  end
end
```

Comment: hi! I have used your method and it says > undefined method after_create. why is that?

Comment: I need more information, what object is it trying to run after_create on? It might be that this is pulled from an old answer.  I think the Factory.define <your factory name> syntax might be depricated.  I'll edit my answer with the up-to-date syntax.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: This is a good answer and what I usually use... except ThoughtBot changed the syntax again (are we there yet?). It should be `after(:create) {...etc`

Answer (score 3):

This is the factory that worked for me

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence :email do |n|
      "address#{n}@example.com"
    end
    sequence :password do |n|
      "password#{n}"
    end

    factory :confirmed_user do
      before(:create) {|user| user.skip_confirmation! }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `User` factory definition:

```
before(:create) { |user| user.skip_confirmation! }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the Devise confirmable logic in the after(:build) callback...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    after(:build) do |u|
      u.confirm!
      u.skip_confirmation_notification!
    end
 ...
end
```

For me, putting confirm! or skip_confirmation! in the after(:create) block caused validation errors on the email parameter and did not work.

Comment: just `u.skip_confirmation!` after build works for me. it also makes user creation faster.

Comment: That's the only thing working in 2020 (just remove the `confirm!`)

Answer (score 1):

You should call `skip_confirmation!` before `create` so this is persisted on the user.

```
before(:create) do |user|
  user.skip_confirmation!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

2023

Does not work:

```
before(:create, &:skip_confirmation!)
```

Works:

```
after(:build, &:skip_confirmation!)
```